# How do I change the xticks to months only?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, seaborn

I am plotting data across a large number of dates. When the plot comes out all the dates overlap each other and becomes a blur. I want would like to change keep the data plots over the whole range of dates but the axis ticks to be months or every two weeks (anything clearer). The dates on the dataset are objects not datetime.See code and image below.

**What do I need to add to rectify the problem. Many thanks.**

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
sns.lineplot(x='Date',y='CurrentPositiveCases', data=worst_areas, hue='RegionName')
```

[image: Notice the dates below all overlapping each other]

Comment: convert your dates to datetime and it will mostly fix the problem.

Comment: Did the answer by FrancecoMartino help you solve your problem? If so, I invite you to [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), else let me know and I can share another solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through ticks and set the interval of visibles:

```
ax = sns.lineplot(x='Date',y='CurrentPositiveCases', data=worst_areas, hue='RegionName')
 
for ind, label in enumerate(ax.get_xticklabels()):
            if ind % 14 == 0:  # every 14th label is kept
                label.set_visible(True)
            else:
                label.set_visible(False)
```